# Blazor blur an element on scroll with js and css

Tags: javascript, css, blazor, blur, onscroll

I'm working on a Blazor web app, and I would like to blur a specific element (background) when the user scrolls.

To achieve this, I called a JS function:

```
function backgroundBlurry() {
var distanceScrolled = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
$('.pageBackground').css({
        filter: "blur(" + (distanceScrolled/10) + "px)"     
    })
}
```

My Razor page:

```
<body class="windowStyle" @onscroll="@Background">
    <div class="pageBackground"/>
</body>

@code{

private async Task Background()
    {            
        await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("backgroundBlurry");
    }
}
```

And here the classes of my css:

```
.windowStyle {
    margin: 0;
    user-select: none;
    overflow: overlay;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #1c2941;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
}

.pageBackground {
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../res/image/web_background.webp);
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: fixed;
    filter: blur(0px);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

My issue here, is the value for `document.scrollingElement.scrollTop` returns 0 on Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

I tried with `$(window).scrollTop()`, `document.body.scrollTop`, `document.documentElement.scrollTop`, and none of them worked.

Did I missed something?

Thank you.

Regards, Samih.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be easier using the scroll event. When scrolling is started add `.blurred` css to the element, and remove it when scrolling is stopped. It could look something like this.

**Html**

```
<div style="min-height:2000px">
  <div class="blur-on-scroll" style="min-height:500px;width:100px"></div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.blurred{
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var blurredElms = document.getElementsByClassName("blur-on-scroll");
    if(timer !== null) {
        // When scrolling is started add the blurred class.
        Array.from(blurredElms).forEach(
            function (element, index, array) {
              element.classList.add('blurred');
            }
        );
    
        clearTimeout(timer);        
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        // When scrolling is stopped, remove blurred class.
        Array.from(blurredElms).forEach(
            function (element, index, array) {
              element.classList.remove('blurred');
            }
        );
          
          
    }, 150);
}, false);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vu4d1g8/5/) I would use CSS transitioning to smooth out the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution, based on @clamchoda answer.

in the js script:

```
window.onscroll = function () {

    var distanceScrolled = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;

    if (distanceScrolled < 200) {

        $('.pageBackground').css({
            filter: "blur(" + (distanceScrolled / 20) + "px)"
        })
    }
};
```

And in the css file, I removed `height:100vh;`.

Before that, window.scroll was not working. After removing the height value, window.scroll worked, and scrollTop returns a correct value.

```
.windowStyle {
    user-select: none;
    overflow: overlay;
    overscroll-behavior: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1c2941;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
}
```

This solution worked for Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

Thanks to Clamchoda, and everyone.

Regards, Samih.